# Set aliases in an R hashtable

Tags: r, hashtable

I'm using the [`hash` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/) to create a sliceable hashtable.

However, I want to have aliases for all of the values (i.e. 2 keys per value).

For example:

```
library(hash)
h = hash(keys = letters, values = 1:26)
# create aliases from the LETTERS collection for the respective values
h[['A']]
> 1
```

I could obviously simply add the aliases to the `keys` parameter and duplicate the `values`:

```
h = hash(keys = c(letters, LETTERS), values = rep(1:26, 2))
values(h)
> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

but then the aliases will actually be pointing to different (if identical) data than the original keys.

Does this package (or some other) allow for many-to-one key-value relationships? Or is there some other way of achieving this with the same O(1) performance?

<sub>It occurs to me now that I could create a second hash table which maps the aliases to the original keys, and then create a function which takes the desired slice as input, finds the slice elements which belong to the alias hash, gets the respective original names, and then collects the values from the original hash. But that seems like a bit of a workaround, so a better solution would be appreciated.</sub>

Comment: I think you're on-track in your (sub)text about a second hash table. I'd think it would be a `alias:name` association. I think you're still relatively close to *O(3)* (which I think is still technically *O(1)*?) performance, because you first check for existence in the first table; if failed, check for presence in the second and perform a lookup/fetch there, then back to the first table. (Caveat: I'm not a regular use of the `hash` package, so I'm commenting mostly theoretically.)

Comment: I'd think it's not an unreasonable feature-request on the package's [github issues](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/r-hash/issues), though I can also see it as possibly "out-of-scope".